# Why does this loop go back to the beginning?

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SteppingStone4_Loops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       String recipeName = "";
       ArrayList<String> ingredientList = new ArrayList();
       String newIngredient = "";
       boolean addMoreIngredients = true;

       System.out.println("Please enter the recipe name: ");
       recipeName = scnr.nextLine();


       do {           
           System.out.println("Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)");
           String reply = scnr.next().toLowerCase();

           /**The code should check the reply:
            *   "y" --> prompt for the ingredient and add it to the ingredient list;
            *   "n" --> break out of the loop;  
            *   anything else --> prompt for a "y" or "n"
            */

          while (true) {
             if (reply.equals("y")) {
               System.out.println("Enter ingredient name: "); 
               newIngredient = scnr.next();   
               ingredientList.add(newIngredient);
             break;
           }
             else if (reply.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
             }

            else  
               break;
           }


            } while (addMoreIngredients);
           for (int i = 0; i < ingredientList.size(); i++) {
           String ingredient = ingredientList.get(i);
           System.out.println(ingredient);
       }
    }
}
```

When ran, the program returns this:

Please enter the recipe name:
Polenta
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)
y
Enter ingredient name:
Salt
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)
n
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)
5
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)

Why doesn't it break when reply = n? Why does it go back to the "Would you like to enter an ingredient"? Can someone pinpoint my mistake or perhaps suggest a different way? Thanks

Comment: You have a `break;` statement whether `reply.equals("y")` or `reply.equals("n")`. Why do you expect them to behave differently?

Comment: Come to think of it, your inner loop never actually loops. If you get rid of it, `break;` will break out of the outer one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (addMoreIngredients);
```

This line always returns true. So your do loop keeps on looping.

I suggest setting a flag from inner loop for outerloop as well.

--edit-----
lets get rid of inner loop, i think it should work fine. 
PS: right now i don't have access to a JRE. But i think it should work

```
do {           
           System.out.println("Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)");
           String reply = scnr.next().toLowerCase();

             if (reply.equals("y")) {
               System.out.println("Enter ingredient name: "); 
               newIngredient = scnr.next();   
               ingredientList.add(newIngredient);
               continue;
           }
             else if (reply.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
             }

            else {
            System.out.println("Invalid option!");
            continue;
            }   
 } while (addMoreIngredients);
```

Comment: How do I set such a flag? I thought that the break command would cause the loop to end.

Comment: @Tulcea65 i have revised my stand, and suggested a code which i think should cater to your requirement. Two loops were not required in your case. This way your code should be more optimized. Please excuse the formatting of code. I dont have any Java ide with me, nor the proper knowledge to align  it here.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion! I ran the code and it does seem to work correctly. NetBeans says that the 2 continue; commands are not necessary, but I will leave them there.

Comment: Yeah, i just put it there, because it makes sense to starters, if you find the answer acceptable, please mark it answered

Answer (score 1):

Please note, you have 2 `while` loops

```
  else if (reply.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            break;
         }
```

The above condition will break out from inner while loop and outer while loop will still continue and that's why you are getting output "Would you like to enter an ingredient", which part of outer loop.

Since, in outer loop, you have below condition, which is set `true` and never seems to be changed.

```
while (addMoreIngredients)
```

So, before breaking out from inner loop, you could change `addMoreIngredients` to `false`

```
  else if (reply.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        addMoreIngredients = false;
        break;
     }
```

Just to let you know, you could also use label break instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check that you have nested loops and break statement in inner loop only break out from inner loop and you apply the second condition of the do-while loop on**
`addMoreIngredients = true`

> break statment only break out the inner loop.
>
> so it always runs because `addMoreIngredients` always true.

Answer (score 0):

make  addMoreIngredients is false

```
 else if (reply.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            addMoreIngredients = false;
            break;
         }
```

Comment: I did that change and it seems to help, but now, when I run the program with the different replies, this is what I get, when I choose 'n':   Please enter the recipe name:   
polenta  
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)  
y  
Enter ingredient name:   
ingredient  
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)  
5  
Would you like to enter an ingredient: (y or n)  
n  
Goodbye!  
ingredient    
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)

Comment: Don't understand why that last input (ingredient) follows the "Goodbye!" when 'n' is chosen...

Comment: if you dont make addMoreingredients=false the break statement will come out of the inner while loop. But to come out of the outer loop it is checking  addMoreingredients variable which is always true. so it wont come out of the outer loop.

Comment: This is the current version of the code (based on the suggestions posted so far):         
            else if (reply.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                addMoreIngredients = false; 
                break;
                }